Is there a file similar to X11's rgb.txt for the 256 colors used in most terminal apps?
We know X11 has rgb.txt file that defines over 700 colors. Is there a similar file that defines the 256 colors (ie., hex code plus name) used in most terminal apps ?
sample lines:
255 250 250             snow
248 248 255             ghost white
248 248 255             GhostWhite


Related: Can I change the default palette for an xterm-256color terminal?

Thanks. I could indeed print the 256 color table on xterm. I am just wondering if there is a standard list that define the color code for each of the 256 colors being adopted in the terminal ?

See also https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number

The default colours in xterm in the 256 colour palette are more or less a RGB encoding.

Why make things so complicated? Use ANSI-colors instead.
Some Python code for you
#!/bin/env python3

CSI = "\x1B["
fg='3'
bg='4'
mode='5'

def setRGB(fgbg, r, g=0, b=0, mde='2'):
    """ set a color on fg or bg 
        mde=2 r;g;b 
        mde=5 r - 0-255, for 256 color mode """
    if mde=='5':    
        return f"{CSI}{fgbg}8;{mde};{r}m"
    return f"{CSI}{fgbg}8;{mde};{r};{g};{b}m"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys    

    for n in range(256):
        print(setRGB(fg,n,mde=mode)+setRGB(bg,254-n,mde=mode)+f' {n:3} ',end='')
        if (n+1)%16==0:
            print(f'{CSI}0m')

    print(f'{CSI}0m')
    

If you intend to use it in windows CMD, add these lines after main:
    # Windows (i.e "nt"), needs ANSI initialized:
    import os
    if os.name=="nt":
        os.system("") # magic to init ANSI -sequences (= load ANSI.SYS for oldish CMD?)


Thanks. Having read up on the topic of 256 colors, appreciate that it is based on ANSI colors.
